# Pandas transpose / pivot / groupby to convert a row values to their own columns with count

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({ 
     'Year': [2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022],
    'Quarter':[2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2],
    'Product':['Car','Bike','Car','Bus','Bike','Bus','Car','Bike'],
    })
df
```

[image]

I am trying to group by `Year` and `Quarter` whilst transposing the `Product` column to have all uniqiue values getting their own column.

My expected output is this, with just a basic count of the values.
Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Use `pd.crosstab([df.Year, df.Quarter], df.Product)`

Comment: Thanks! when i add this code to a bigger dataset, it only shows 1 row and does not group by the Year and Quarter. Any ideas?

Comment: Seems some data related problem, no idea

Comment: Yes it was a data error sorry! thanks

Comment: Another question - is there a way to have the cross tab become a normal dataframe? So i could perform joins onto it?

Comment: Sure, add `.reset_index()`